# Trying to add bfseries to numbers only

Tags: minitoc

I need to only have bfseries on the numbers that indicate the section and not the subsection, like this:

[image]

I have tried the following commands, but still, I cant get it:

```
\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small}

\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\mtcSSfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\mtcSSSfont}{\small}
```

mwe:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc% Initialization
\tableofcontents

\chapter{bla}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc

\section{blubb}

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post ² *complete* code, that we can compile?

Comment: @Bernard I have done it

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont} % non bold chapter header
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % bold page numbers` helps.

Comment: @leandriis It did work, thx!

Comment: @leandriis -- That looks line an answer.  Please add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `tocloft` package you can control the style of every single element of the table of contents. To make the chapter headings non bold but keep the corrensponding page numbers bold, we can redefine `\cftchapfont` as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont} % non bold chapter header

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc% Initialization
\tableofcontents

\chapter{bla}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc

\section{blubb}

\section{foo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it actually the size of the font of the Tex document? I mean, I am working with a book class 11pt a4paper. By doing what you did I think the size of the font i.e. `\normalfont` is smaller than those 11pt.

Comment: @NaveganTeX: To be honest, I don't see any difference. Could you please upload a screenshot showing the difference in font sizes?